# Rewrite rule with two variables if first variable is "profile"

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Excuse my English,

I'm currently rewriting [ example.com/about -> example.com?page=about ]

I'd like to rewrite a second variable if the page requested is "profile", hence making [ example.com/profile/johndoe -> example.com?page=profile&name=johndoe ]

In other words; The only case where a second variable is needed is if the page requested is Profile. Is this possible to make as a rewrite rule?

Thanks a lot in advance,

I currently use this:

```
RewriteEngine On

# WWW-Rewrite

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]


# Remove trailing slash(es)

    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 


# Rewrite /sth  ->  ?page=sth

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

    RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/?$ /?page=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

just change your htaccess except www-rewrite and trailing slash

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^profile/(.*)$ page=profile&name=$1[L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ page=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Thanks for your response but it didn't work for me, "Internal Server Error" :(